# Android dependency shading plugin

Tags: android, gradle

I am working on a Android library which is using okhttp dependency. I want to shade this dependency so that it doesn't conflict in the app in case if the app is also using the same dependency but with different versions.

I saw a couple of gradle shade plugins but none were compatible with Android.

Comment: https://github.com/shevek/jarjar. Are you sure a transitive dependency is not enough?

Comment: excluding transitive dependency is not enough as the versions can break the compatibility

Comment: OkHttp uses artifact naming and versioning that guarantees you either OkHttp 2 or OkHttp 3. On top of that you can specify transitive dependency in your library such as "3.2.0" and gradle will ensure the least included version of OkHttp3 in the consumer project is 3.2.0. Of course if you're depending on private APIs that are only available in a certain version of OkHttp repackaging may be a tempting option. As a potential consumer I'd rather your library worked well with (in this case) any OkHttp 3 above a version of your choosing instead of having to have two copies of OkHttp in my apk.

Comment: TL;DR: For a resource constrained environment, which Android is, make your lib work with any transitively included version of OkHttp3 above a version of your choosing and the latest available.

Comment: It is not an easy job to force my consumers to force use OkHttp >= 3.2.0
Changing the version requires time as testing of the apps are required. This can be problematic for me in future.